# Why do I get the error, XML_IO_FLUSH, with xmlDocDump

Tags: xml, fopen, libxml2

With modes "w", "w+"  and "w+b", I get XML_IO_FLUSH.

With the file open, I can successfully call fputs() and fclose() with proper, expected results.

BTW: I work around the problem using xmlDocDumpFormatMemory() and handling the file IO separate from libxml2.

EDIT: I was able to move beyond the original issue when calling setvbuf() using this code:

```
MSEXPORT int WriteXMLDocFile(xmlDocPtr doc, char* filename) //  Write Doc to file
{
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) return -2;
    
    #define BUFSIZE 1024
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int err = setvbuf(fp, buf, _IOFBF, BUFSIZE);
            snprintf(dan, BUFSZ, "err = %d   BUFSIZ = %d", err, BUFSIZE); DEBUG_MSG(dan);
    
    int rtn_val = xmlDocDump(fp, doc);
            snprintf(dan, BUFSZ, "size = %d", rtn_val); DEBUG_MSG(dan);
    fclose(fp);
    
    return rtn_val;
}
```

Though while it yields the expected length, crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around the issue by using `xmlSaveFile()` instead of `xmlDocDump()`